# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, api, foreach

The idea is that whatever is searched will bring back a bit of text and an image from a separate API. The text works completely fine but the image is not appearing.

The full message error is:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at Jdata.records.forEach.item and at Array.forEach

```
 request.addEventListener("load", function() {


            if (request.status == 200) {
                var Jdata = request.response;
                Jdata.records.forEach(item => {

                    var results = document.getElementById("results");
                    var title = item.fields.title;
                    console.log(item.fields.title);

                    if (item.fields.hasOwnProperty('p_tag')) {
                        var fname = item.p_tag.substring(0,6);
                        var fid = item.fields.p_tag;
                        var image = `https://media.vam.ac.uk/media/thira/collection_images/${fname}/${fid}.jpg`;

                        var img2 = document.createElement('img');
                        img2.src = image;



                    }

                    else{

                    }

                    let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
                    h2.textContent = title;

                    results.appendChild(h2);
                    results.appendChild(img2);



                })



        } else {
            console.log("error: "+xhr.status);
        }

    });
    request.send();
```

Comment: You have an empty `else` branch. When the code takes that path `img2` isn't set and is `undefined`

Comment: @JaredSmith unfortunately the uncaught TypeError still stays exactly the same even after adding to the else

Comment: Edit your question with your updated code.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have written the code in the answer

Comment: Again, please edit the code into your question, unless you actually answered your own question (which is totally allowed but doesnt seem to be the case here).

Answer (score 0):

function action () {

```
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    results.textContent = "";
    console.log(results);
    var sbar = document.getElementById("searchi").value;
    console.log(sbar);


    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    var url = 'https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?q='+sbar;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType ='json';

    console.log("button was clicked");


    request.addEventListener("load", function() {


        if (request.status == 200) {
            var Jdata = request.response;
            Jdata.records.forEach(item => {

                var results = document.getElementById("results");
                var title = item.fields.title;
                console.log(item.fields.title);

                if (item.fields.hasOwnProperty('p_tag')) {
                    var fname = item.p_tag.substring(0,6);
                    var fid = item.fields.p_tag;
                    var image = `https://media.vam.ac.uk/media/thira/collection_images/${fname}/${fid}.jpg`;

                    var img2 = document.createElement('img');
                    img2.src = image;



                }

                else{
                    console.log("error");


                }

                let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
                h2.textContent = title;

                results.appendChild(h2);
                results.appendChild(img2);



            })



        } else {
            console.log("error: "+xhr.status);
        }

    });
    request.send();
};
```